# very strange issue with UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So here's the code:

```
UISegmentedControl * segmentedCtrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 35)];
    //[segmentedCtrl setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    [segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmentedCtrl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
    [segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
    [segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] atIndex:2 animated:NO];

    [segmentedCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [segmentedCtrl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    //[segmentedCtrl setMomentary:YES];
    [segmentedCtrl.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [segmentedCtrl.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

However, when I press the segmented control I am getting this:

[image]

Any idea to remove the blue highlight?

Here's a sample project that I zipped that shows this issue:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19680269/Test.zip

Comment: Did you try with other picture to know if its the picture or not? You can then maybe try to remove a subview of your UISegmentedControl subviews.

Comment: Have you tried setting tintColor to `[UIColor clearColor];`?

Comment: yes I have.. I have attached the project.. it's very simple now, just a UIViewController with a UISegmentedButton

Comment: it crashes to me at this line of code:       [segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: oh ok, it crashes just on a 4.3 simulator, it's ok for iOS 5

Comment: @meronix yes, it's for iOS 5.. were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code...

I solved the problem by adding this code

[image]

```
[segmentedCtrl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled];
```

So the entire code will be like this

```
UISegmentedControl * segmentedCtrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 35)];
//[segmentedCtrl setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[segmentedCtrl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled];
[segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] atIndex:0 animated:NO];
[segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] atIndex:1 animated:NO];
[segmentedCtrl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] atIndex:2 animated:NO];

[segmentedCtrl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
//[segmentedCtrl setMomentary:YES];
[segmentedCtrl.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
[segmentedCtrl.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
```

Comment: Previously it was taking the default style

Comment: so you had setSegmentedControlStyle twice

Comment: Did you actually try to click on the segment and see if the blue appears. The blue highlight appears only when you click on it.. in my case it still appears with your code above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11734/discussion-between-adit-and-krrish)

Comment: and you had one, two, three.. but in your code you had set the segment with a nil image which is contradictary

Answer (score 0):

you may add a separator png file:

```
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

ps:

why did you add it twice to your view?

```
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

**EDIT:**

if you don't really need the separators between your segmented you can just remove them this way:

```
for (UIView* aSubV in segmentedControl.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"•••");
    NSLog(@"aSubV2: %@",[aSubV.subviews objectAtIndex:1]);
    UIView* separatorToRemove = [aSubV.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    [separatorToRemove removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

Adding this line in `viewDidLoad` of `MCSegmentedControlDemoViewController.m` fixed the bug.
The blue color is the highlight color of the normal segment view.

When you set background for normal segment, it doesn cover entirely. so you see the blue in edges.

Making it bar styled makes your image cover the entire segment. Hence you won't see blue color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but if you use the code below the result will be:

[image]

Changes to your code:

- you're adding `segmentedControl` to `self.view` two times - removed first occurance
- added `[segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];`

There's a 1px green line between segments - this is due to your line:

```
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.0 green:.6 blue:.0 alpha:1.0];
```

If you want the line to be of some other color just change the `tintColor` property.

The complete `viewDidLoad` looks like:

Code was not modifed anywhere else.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1.0];
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"one",
                      @"two",
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"],
                      nil];

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];

    // set frame, add to view, set target and action for value change as usual
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 208.0f, 300.0f, 44.0f);
    //[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

    [segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

    // Set a tint color
    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.0 green:.6 blue:.0 alpha:1.0];

    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    [segmentedControl release];    
}
```